# Is there any difference between the tags "windows-server-2003" and "windows-2003-server"?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Discovered a few semi-related tags:

[windows-server-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2003)

*539 questions, 10 this year

this has a good excerpt, but no tag wiki*

[windows-2003-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-2003-server)

*19 questions, 2 this year

this has nothing... no excerpt, no wiki*

---

Each of these tags has questions asked in the past year.

**Are these tags for the same thing? Should they be merged together?**

Comment: Good catch! I think the first one should be the correct tag.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Agreed. Windows Server 2003 appears to be the main tag and lines up with the actual product name.

Merged and synonymised.

```
updating post history, 22 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 19 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 19 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 558
tag remapping of [windows-server-2003] and [windows-2003-server] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym windows-2003-server -> windows-server-2003 was approved!
```

There was also a [windows-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-2003) which I have merged into [windows-server-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2003)